# From $(\Gamma_1,\ldots,\Gamma_n)$ conditionally on $\Gamma_{n+1}$, to $(\Gamma_1/\Gamma_{n+1},\ldots,\Gamma_n/\Gamma_{n+1})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm reading a text where the author uses a lemma which states

> If $\{E_i\}$ are iid unit exponential random variables, and, for every $k$, $\Gamma_k=\sum\limits_{i=0}^kE_i$, then $$(\Gamma_1,...,\Gamma_n|\Gamma_{n+1}=t)\sim
>  (U_{(1)},...,U_{(n)})$$

where $(U_{(1)},...,U_{(n)})$ is joint distribution of the order statistics taken from an iid $\text{Unif}(0,t)$.

However, the author restates later in the text the lemma as 
$$\left(\frac{\Gamma_1}{\Gamma_{n+1}},...,\frac{\Gamma_n}{\Gamma_{n+1}}\right)\sim
 (U_{(1)},...,U_{(n)})$$
where $(U_{(1)},...,U_{(n)})$ is joint distribution of the order statistics taken from an iid $\text{Unif}(0,1)$.

How are they able to transform one into the other?

This is from Resnick's *Adventures in Stochastic Processes*. The lemma is in page 322, and the reformulation in 530.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $$U=(U_{(1)},\ldots,U_{(n)})$$ is distributed as the order statistics of an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ from $\text{Unif}(0,1)$, and consider the random vector $$\Gamma=(\Gamma_1,\ldots,\Gamma_{n})$$ introduced in the question. Then, for every $t>0$, $$t\cdot U$$ is distributed as the order statistics of an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ from $\text{Unif}(0,t)$ hence one knows that $$(\Gamma\mid\Gamma_{n+1}=t)\stackrel{d}{=}
 t\cdot U$$ Thus, for every $t$,
$$(\Gamma_{n+1}^{-1}\cdot \Gamma\mid\Gamma_{n+1}=t)=(t^{-1}\cdot \Gamma\mid\Gamma_{n+1}=t)\stackrel{d}{=}U$$ This proves that the conditional distribution $$(\Gamma_{n+1}^{-1}\cdot \Gamma\mid\Gamma_{n+1}=t)$$ does not depend on $t$, hence this distribution is also the (absolute) distribution of $$\Gamma_{n+1}^{-1}\cdot \Gamma$$ In other words, $$(\Gamma_{n+1}^{-1}\cdot\Gamma_1,\ldots,\Gamma_{n+1}^{-1}\cdot\Gamma_{n})=\Gamma_{n+1}^{-1}\cdot \Gamma\stackrel{d}{=}U$$

Comment: I like your answers, because everyone can understand it! So simple, so neat, so good!

Comment: @Shashi Thanks (for the plural...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Did.